# Do i need to add URLs for flat pages in url.py in django

Tags: django, django-flatpages

I have enabled flat pages in django

and created page with url `/pages/about`

so i want to know that do i need to create some url in url.py or not

Because when i try `http://ip:8000/pages/about` it say page not found

Also when i created page it asked me to select site  but iam only using ipaddress, can that be the reason

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to add any urls. The Flatpages middleware kicks in when all of your defined urls fail. There's more info in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/#how-it-works) describing how it works.

Comment: I have done all the steps but i get error pages not found  `http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8000/pages/about/` . what should i do

Comment: I'd double check the installation steps and make sure you've done them correctly.

Comment: The only thing which i think is i don't have any domain name configured. is that the case or it will work on ip address as well

Comment: As long as you've made the site (in the Django admin), and set the SITE_ID in your settings, using the ip should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/

and especially [this part of the guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/#limiting-flatpages-by-base-url) shows how you have to configure your urls to use your flatpages

Answer (score 0):

Include this single line code in your root urls.py file

```
url(r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

and create flat page file with simple url `/about/`

Done!!

**It works for me**